# cakephp2.10 stop loop of form results

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp-2.x

Please, I need your help, I think I identified my problem but no solutions.

context: I've an ajax table of products, each line of table has a button to sell the product. When you click, a modal is open with product caracteristics that you can change and when you valid your modal, those caracteristics are saved in the corresponding database.

Problem: It works perfectly for the first product; but from the second product, I got an error message:
"Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '22-1' pour la clef 'PRIMARY' etc"
**And, anyway, the second product is sold.** which is already a good point.
Of course, if I refresh the entire page, it's good, but it's not the idea.

So I checked and I realised that all the precedents caracteristics from the first product has been also sent and of course the application try to save again in the database that product, which try to create a duplicata. It's a kind of loop of the results form.

a bit of code to be more precised:

Fonction javascript which send to the modal the caracteristics of the product which has the number: data-numero. It send to the ColisController, in the function Vendre, in GET:

```
                $(this).click(function() {
                    var numero = $(this).attr('data-numero');

                    ajax('<?php echo CHEMIN_BASE ?>/Colis/vendre/'+numero, {}, 'div-modal', 'div-erreurs');
                    $('#titre-modal').html("Vendre un colis");
                    $('#modal').modal('show');
                });
            });
```

ColisController, function vendre

```
    public function vendre($numeroColis = null) {
        if($this->request->is('GET')) {
            $prix = $this->Coli->getPrix($numeroColis);
            $clients = $this->Coli->Vendu->Client->listeClients();
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->set(compact('prix', 'observation', 'clients', 'numeroColis'));
        }
        else if($this->request->is('POST')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
            $numero = $data['numero'];
            if(isset($data['prix']))
                $this->Coli->setPrix($numero, $data['prix']);

                $this->Coli->vendreColi($numero, $data['id-client']);
                $this -> request -> data(null);
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Colis', 'action' => 'vendus'));
        }
        else 
            throw new Exception("vendre() attend une requête GET ou POST");
    }
```

modal of "vendre", function javascript to take the caracteristics of the product and sent it in POST to the action Vendre of the ColisController

```
$(function() {
    $('#modal-valider').click(function() {

        var parametres = {
            'numero': $('#numeroducolis').val(),
            'prix': $('#prix').val(),
            'id-client': $('#id-client').val(),
        };
        ajax('<?php echo CHEMIN_BASE ?>/Colis/vendre', parametres, 'div-colis-vendus', 'div-erreurs', null, 'POST');
        //Mise à jour du stock (pour effacement du colis qui vient d'être vendu)
        setTimeout(function() {
            ajax('<?php echo CHEMIN_BASE ?>/Colis/stock', null, 'div-colis-stock', 'div-erreurs', null, 'GET');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

function setprix in the model Coli

```
    public function setPrix($numeroColis, $prix) {
        if(! $this->exists($numeroColis))
            throw new Exception("Colis : $numeroColis inexistant");

        $this->id = $numeroColis;
        $this->saveField('prix', $prix);
    }
```

function vendreColis in the model Coli:

```
    public function vendreColi($numero, $idClient) {
        //Vérifications
        if(! $this->Vendu->Client->exists($idClient))
            throw new Exception("Client id: $idClient inexistant");
        if(! $this->exists($numero))
            throw new Exception("Colis numéro: $numero inexistant");

        $this->Vendu->create(array(
            'numero_colis' => $numero,
            'id_client' => $idClient,
            'date_vente' => date('Y-m-d'),
        ));
        $this->Vendu->save();

        return true;
    }
```

and after that it will set again the updated table vendu ("sold') and the updated table stock.

I tried many things like: empty "parametres" in the modal, or empty the value of the inputs in the form of the modal, or also in the controller:

```
$this -> request -> data(null);
```

or

```
$this -> data = null;
```

but, no change.
in the case that I try to sell a second product, data will be empty but it will try to sell twice my second product (and 3 times if I sell a third product).
I don't understand how to stop the fact that it knows I sent the form before, and it tries to sent again the last values!

Please, it would be very nice if you can help me

Comment: At a quick scan, there's nothing obviously wrong. If you check the network monitor in your browser when this happens, is it one request sent with two blocks of data, or two requests each with one block?

Comment: Also, you've included `$('#modal').modal('show');` and `$('#modal-valider').click(function() {`, but nothing that connects those two things.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your help,

Comment: To your first message, it's two requests each with one block. and about your second message, it's an interesting point, attt the moment there is no connections and they are not on the same view. I will check, when I can, what I can improve about that. If you have inspiration or idea about how to do it, I'm interested. :) Thanks again

Comment: Hey Greg, what do you think of remove listeners?

Comment: I don't know enough JavaScript to have an opinion one way or the other.